# How many cards to get a pair

Tags: probability

A person is playing a game where $54$ cards are placed face down on a table. The game is to two turn cards face up to try to get a pair, since there are $27$ pairs of matching cards. After a long streak of no pairs, the person gets frustrated and decides to just start flipping cards until he gets a pair. How many cards would he have to flip before there is a $50\%$ chance that the flipped cards contain at least one pair?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we flip $k$ cards. There are $\binom{54}{k}$ ways to get $k$ cards. Now we count the no pair hands of $k$. There are $\binom{27}{k}$ ways to choose the $k$ types, and for every way of choosing the types there are $2^k$ ways to choose the actual cards. So the probability of no pairs is
$$\frac{2^k\binom{27}{k}}{\binom{54}{k}}.\tag{1}$$
We want (at least) a $50\%$ chance of at least one pair, so we want the least $k$ such that $(1)$ dips below $0.5$.  For the actual calculation, it is easier to use the fact that (1) is equivalent to
$$\frac{54}{54}\cdot \frac{52}{53}\cdot \frac{50}{52}\cdot \frac{48}{51}\cdots \cdot \frac{54-2k+2}{54-k+1}.\tag{2}$$
Now the partial products $\frac{52}{53}$, $\frac{52}{53}\cdot \frac{50}{52}$, and so on can be found by calculator until we get below $0$.